# SSRS. Autosize font to fit textbox width

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Is it possible in SSRS to set the Font Size to auto? So the text fits exactly to the width of a text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, no.

For practical reasons, some of which I can think of:

- there is a lower bound to font size so some text will never fit
- height changes too so for sparse text you get vertical growth

Comment: Makes sense. How about shrinking the size only if the text is wider than the width of the text box?

Comment: @tou: that kind of width adjustment is tricky even in full-on dotnet for a proportional font. I really think your only option is a custom assembly for that. With a fixed width font you could do it, maybe, knowing textbox width and number of characters by some basic maths

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the only solution. I have a fixed width. The only thing is that my text can be translated and the font(type/size/etc) can be chosen by the user.